# report on live agents salesfoce

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud, custom-report-type, omnichannel

I'd like to create a report on agent login, logout time, login duration, break time, status, average handling time, average speed of answer, total number of calls, email, cases, etc in the salesforce service cloud

Any help will be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check free [Omni-channel Performance Dashboard](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G0yalUAB) AppExchange tool to understand agent productivity and workload.